# JAVA : passing objects

Tags: java

Suppose I have an object of some class `c`.

I insert this to two arraylists of type `c`, `d1` and `d2`.

If I change this object in `d1` , will it change in `d2`.

If not, is there any method in which I could do so?

P.S. I am new to JAVA

Comment: No I didn't..... Let me try it first

Comment: Yes it did... but how????

Comment: c is not an object. It's a reference (a pointer, if you prefer) to an object. When you add c to the lists, you pass them a copy of this reference. So the two lists each have a reference to the same object. Changing the state of the object change it everywhere, since there is a single object. The lists are still referencing the same object, whose state has been modified.

Comment: Does it happen for primitive types too like int??? What if I do not want this feature???

Comment: Have you tried creating a `List<int>`? Have you tried changing the internal state of an int? Do primitives have methods to change their state? If you do not want this feature, then make immutable objects, whose state can never change, or create copies of your objects before passing them.

Comment: Also, a single question mark is sufficient. No need to use 3 or 4 question marks in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Java passes objects by references to objects by value . This means, that when you store an object somewhere and modify it in another location, the stored object will change.

When you pass an object, you do not pass the data itself, but a reference, which is like a pointer to the location where the object is stored. In all places you're accessing the same piece of memory!

Comment: You'll get downvoted quickly if you don't change your wording. Java doesn't pass objects by references. It passes references to objects by value.